# SSL Partially breaking admin panel and elementor

Tags: wp-admin, admin, ssl, https

I have recently installed a SSL certificate on my hosting server and I switched WordPress to SSL.
The website is running normally, with no mixed content errors and everything is loading as it should. I have run search and replace for all links to replace with https.

The problem is the admin panel. For example when I go to themes and try to add a new one, I get no output and I have some errors in the console (see attached picture). Also when I try to edit a page built with Elementor, over SSL, it does not load.
Also when over SSL, customize panel on the page does not load.

Everything is normal if I switch over to plain HTTP.
My php version is 5.6

[image: Admin area over SSL]

### Update on the issue

The error is not shown anymore and I am not getting any error output on the console, nor I'm getting any errors logged, with WP_DEBUGGING enabled. The problems still persist.

#### In summary the errors are:

- Add new theme page does not fully load, so does add new plugins
- Edit using elementor does not work (elementor is not loading)
- Customization menu does not load on the page

All the above errors are present when the website is over SSL. Any redirections, URL fixes have been taken care of.

Comment: is jquery loading after all your plugins?  Im sure you do but make sure you have https in the admin settings.  Maybe try adding define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); in wp-config.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I do have FORCE_SSL_ADMIN enabled, but this is not the issue.

Comment: u have https in settings > general?  Just ruling out the basics.  Maybe it would be beneficial to say in your question how you setup your SSL.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Yes it is all set.

Comment: https://docs.elementor.com/article/218-i-changed-the-url-of-my-website-and-elementor-does-not-work-anymore

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Thank you for the reply, but I did that already.

Comment: ¿Have you made a search in table wp-options for http://your_siten_name.com?

Comment: @juananruiz Yes and it is correctly set to https://

Comment: I think you'll have to debug the script error at the top of the list, and work out where it's coming from - which script is it, and does the formatted version form (the '{}' button) look sensible? You can also try defining SCRIPT_DEBUG in wp-config to get WordPress to serve the original not-minified version in case that helps.

Comment: @Rup I did find the file and it was ok, with no missing {}. By the way, for some reason now this error is gone, I get no error in the console, but the problems persist. I'll write an update on the post.

Comment: If it's still not working and you aren't getting any more script errors then I'd guess you're getting PHP errors now. Can you check the server logs?

Comment: @Rup I just checked, there are no logged errors on the server logs.

Comment: https://docs.elementor.com/article/234-ssl-certificate-with-elementor

Comment: @vancoder Thank you for the response. I have already done both.

Comment: Are getting any errors in the network tab of your inspector? You should also check here for broken https requests, mixed content issues, and CORS problems.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I hadn't checked that! When I am in the admin panel over SSL, the admin-ajax.php is not transferred, but the link I get for it contains the https:// prefix. Also when I try to customize the page the file "customize.php" has the same behavior as the "admin-ajax.php" file. Both of the files have https:// prefixes.

Another thing I noticed is that the loading time for the aforementioned files is at the range of 58-60 seconds, which means the files are sent but almost 1 minute later after the page loads. Again everything returns to normal when I disable the SSL.

Comment: These are both ajax requests. Make sure the correct domain and protocol is being used. I'm afraid that's all I can tell you without seeing the requests myself.